# LOG4J Deadlock On ConsoleAppender

Tags: java, log4j, stdout, deadlock, consoleappender

LOG4J seems to lock my consoleappender. If my consoleappender is locked by LOG4J, would also succeeding threads have a hard time writing to my stout and stderr?

How many threads at a time can write to the stdout?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen log4j be blocked / locked by anything. What is making you think it's at fault?

Comment: What is your consoleappender writing to? A shell, Eclipse, a windows command shell, a file (via a redirection)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/634147/603516. Console output must be consumed or it would eventually hang.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread can write to `sysout`/`syserr`. This is actually good, otherwise your logging statements would get mixed terribly.

I don't think Log4J deadlocks on `ConsoleAppender` (stack dump would be very useful). Maybe you are logging too much and other threads are waiting, but eventually reach the console?